# Call back from styled radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin radiosToSlider (http://rubentd.com/radios-to-slider/) and need to make sure that all radio button groups are checked and to give an alert when they are

I can do this if they are just radio buttons by checking the length but because the plugin changes the input buttons I am having difficulties

My fiddle  is 
http://jsfiddle.net/yFaAj/270/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".radios").radiosToSlider();
});


$(":radio").change(function () {
    var names = {};
    $(':radio').each(function () {
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });
    var count = 0;
    $.each(names, function () {
        count++;
    });
    if ($(':radio:checked').length === count) {
        alert("all answered");
    }
}).change();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the plugin changes your structure (although it does add some `ins` elements, which I don't agree with), it's that the plugin doesn't fire a `change` event for the converted radio controls, and setting the `checked` property interactively doesn't appear to do so either.

Since the plugin author doesn't publish an API for this use case, it's hard to know whether this is by design or oversight, but the source code definitely doesn't fire the event when the slider is clicked:

```
this.bearer.find('.slider-level').click( function(){
    var radioId = $(this).attr('data-radio');
    slider.bearer.find('#' + radioId).prop('checked', true);
    slider.setSlider();
});
```

Your options, as I see them:

1. Contact the API author and ask for a bug fix, or the intended way to support this case

   - Downside: Time: dependent on the author to respond
2. Attach your "check" function to the `click` event of the `.slider-level` class, as the API does.

   - Downside: Brittle: future versions of the plugin may attach the behavior to different selectors
3. Attach your function to the `click` event of your radio group, and catch click events on the bubble

   - Downside: Inefficient: It will check for every click in the radio control

Here's a sample implementation of option 3. **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pisida/2/edit)**.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".radios").radiosToSlider();
});

var makeIsRadioGroupChecked = function(selector) {
  var $radioGroup = $(selector);
  return function isRadioGroupChecked() {
    return $radioGroup.find(':checked').length > 0;
  };
};

var isOptionsChecked = makeIsRadioGroupChecked('#optionsRadioGroup');

var isSizeChecked = makeIsRadioGroupChecked('#sizeRadioGroup');

var areAllGroupsChecked = function() {
  return isOptionsChecked() && isSizeChecked();
};

var alertIfAllGroupsChecked = function() {
  if (areAllGroupsChecked()) {
    alert("all answered");
  }
};

$('.radios').on('click', alertIfAllGroupsChecked);
```